# PayPal with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-addin

When connecting PayPal functionality to SharePoint application it is required to set up Security Protocol Type to Tls. PayPal Security Guidelines state that PayPal merchants should be using TLS v1.2 or higher. .NET 3.5 (and below) is not compatible with TLS 1.1 or higher encryption. Buts SharePoint 2010 needs .NET Framework 3.5 or .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Seems that PayPal is not possible to connect to SP 2010?